# Creating an arc with a given thickness using PIL's Imagedraw

Tags: python, image, drawing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to create a segmented arc using PIL and Imagedraw. The arc function allows me to draw an arc easily, but it is just a line. I need to be able to place an arc of given radius and thickness(ID to OD), but AI cannot find any type of thickness or width setting. Is there a way to do this? If not, is there some other way to do this using PIL?

Snippet:

```
import Image
import ImageDraw

conv = 0.1
ID = 15
OD = 20
image = Image.new('1',(int(ceil(OD/conv))+2,int(ceil(OD/conv))+1), 1)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
diam = OD-ID
box=(1, 1, int(ceil(diam/conv)), int(ceil(diam/conv))) #create bounding box
draw.arc(box, 0, 90, 0) #draw circle in black
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A trick I found that can be pulled is to make a white circle inside the black circle. You can use the pieslice method to break it up as needed. The rendering is sequential, so you just have to get the ordering correct. The hard part is getting the positioning correct, due to Imagedraw's use of bounding boxes as opposed to center and radius coordinates. You have to make sure that the centers of everything end up exactly on each other.

THIS SOLUTION IS GOOD ONLY IN A LIMITED CASE, see comment.

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to cheat. Doesn't work if there's anything already drawn on the inner part of the arc.

Comment: Never mind, this is good only if you want ever expanding gaps. If you want fix arclengths to be missing, this does not do the trick.

Comment: you can also use the line command if yo9u very carefully offset

Answer (score 3):

I created the following arc replacement function based on [Mark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5987/mark-ransom)'s suggestion:

https://gist.github.com/skion/9259926

Probably not pixel perfect (nor fast), but seems to come close for what I need it for. If you have a better version please comment in the Gist.

```
def arc(draw, bbox, start, end, fill, width=1, segments=100):
    """
    Hack that looks similar to PIL's draw.arc(), but can specify a line width.
    """
    # radians
    start *= math.pi / 180
    end *= math.pi / 180

    # angle step
    da = (end - start) / segments

    # shift end points with half a segment angle
    start -= da / 2
    end -= da / 2

    # ellips radii
    rx = (bbox[2] - bbox[0]) / 2
    ry = (bbox[3] - bbox[1]) / 2

    # box centre
    cx = bbox[0] + rx
    cy = bbox[1] + ry

    # segment length
    l = (rx+ry) * da / 2.0

    for i in range(segments):

        # angle centre
        a = start + (i+0.5) * da

        # x,y centre
        x = cx + math.cos(a) * rx
        y = cy + math.sin(a) * ry

        # derivatives
        dx = -math.sin(a) * rx / (rx+ry)
        dy = math.cos(a) * ry / (rx+ry)

        draw.line([(x-dx*l,y-dy*l), (x+dx*l, y+dy*l)], fill=fill, width=width)
```

Comment: Nice, thanks! One nit: [Draw.arc()](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/ImageDraw.html#PIL.ImageDraw.PIL.ImageDraw.Draw.arc) accepts `270, 0` as arguments to draw an arc from noon to 3 o'clock. The code above worked only with `270, 360`.

Answer (score 1):

PIL can't draw wide arcs, but [Aggdraw](http://effbot.org/zone/pythondoc-aggdraw.htm) can, and works well with PIL (same author).

Comment: I worked out a complicated nesting scheme whereby I draw arcs with pixel thickness radius changes to get thick lines, but the result is too scalloped at the ends because imagedraw will only accept integer values for angle.

Answer (score 0):

Simulate the arc using straight line segments and put the coordinates of those segments into a list. Use `draw.line` with a `width` option to draw the arc.